# Docker mount ownership inconsistent

Tags: docker

EDIT: I'm on Linux, Docker version `20.10.11`

I've created a super-simple Docker image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2018.03
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I've then run it using Docker run, with a mount point set:

```
docker run -it -v <a directory on my computer>:/theshare <image id>
```

On running `ls -laht /`, the entry for the `/theshare` folder is as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x.   7 1000 1000 4.0K Mar  8  2021 theshare
```

uid 1000 is my user on the host machine, and the folder permissions match the permissions for the folder on the host as well.

Running `ls -laht /theshare` results in:

```
ls: cannot open directory /theshare: Permission denied
```

A colleague, running an image generated from the same dockerfile with the same mount, on the same version of Docker, seens the `/theshare` directory owned by `root` and can access it fine.

I've recently reinstalled my computer, and it worked fine beforehand. I'm assuming I've missed a post-install step for Docker somewhere, but I can't work out what it is.

Comment: Is this docker desktop for Mac, windows, or the engine on Linux? Did the directory exist before running the docker command in every example?

Comment: I'm running on Linux. The directory always existed.